# Populating a 2d array with a from a data member of an object, using a list of object

Tags: java, list, class, iteration, data-members

Okay, I am rather new to java and I really need some help! I have a class named `Teams` and have already have a previously established the `List <Teams> checkedInTeams;` but now I need to populate a 2d array with a specific data member from the `Teams` listed in `checkedInTeams`. I have tried `temp = checkedInTeams.listIterator(0).getTeamNum();` I am not sure where to go.

Ok... I think I might have it worked out some, but the function is creating a parsing error, and I not sure how to proceed:

```
public void setMatchList(int[][] matchList) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfMatches; i++)
        for (Team team : checkedInTeams)
        {
            if (i == 1){
                if (checkedInTeams.indexOf(team)== 0)
                    this.matchList[i][checkedInTeams.size()-1]  = team.getTeamNum();
            }
            if (i == 2){
                if (checkedInTeams.indexOf(team)== 0)
                    this.matchList[i][checkedInTeams.size()-2]  = team.getTeamNum();
                if (checkedInTeams.indexOf(team)== 1)
                    this.matchList[i][checkedInTeams.size()-1]  = team.getTeamNum();
            }
            if (i == 3){
                if (checkedInTeams.indexOf(team)== 0)
                    this.matchList[i][checkedInTeams.size()-3]  = team.getTeamNum();
                if (checkedInTeams.indexOf(team)== 1)
                    this.matchList[i][checkedInTeams.size()-2]  = team.getTeamNum();
                if (checkedInTeams.indexOf(team)== 2)
                    this.matchList[i][checkedInTeams.size()-1]  = team.getTeamNum();
            }
            this.matchList[i][checkedInTeams.indexOf(team)-i]  = team.getTeamNum();
        }
}
```

Ok, hopefully the new question is better, since I believe I figured out how to accomplish my first problem, the above code is my latest attempt. Basically I am trying to populate a 2d array using a specific data-member of an object, using a list of the particular object. As I am populating the array I am trying to create a slight sliding window effect... I hope that this isn't to confusing.

Comment: What do you have written so far?

Comment: I might have gotten it figured out, still struggling a little, I decided to use an enhanced for loop:
    public void setMatchList(int[][] matchList) {
        
        this.matchList = new int[numOfMatches][checkedInTeams.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfMatches; i++)
            for (Team team : checkedInTeams)
            {
                matchList[i][checkedInTeams.indexOf(team)]  = team.getTeamNum();
            }

}

Comment: I still want to try to make this a sliding window, so that the the first element for the first row, would be the last element for the second row... probably can work it out with a few if statements

Comment: please update the question with the most up-to-date code and try to explain your question more clearly, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish thus can't help. But I do see a mistake in how you're appending to the `matchList` array

Comment: I don't see what you're having an issue with, your code from a high level looks right to me

Comment: I don't know what the issue is either, the compiler is showing an error for the function, stating that i have "reached the end of file while parsing"